# Closing duplicates when neither has an answer (yet)

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've found two questions that are **obvious** duplicates:

. [Creating a Trigger to Delete the rows before updating a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349118/creating-a-trigger-to-delete-the-rows-before-updating-a-column)
. [Writing a Trigger in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348584/writing-a-trigger-in-db2)

However, as neither question yet has an answer (given some of the problems in the question...), I can't flag the question as a duplicate.  Either so other users can help close, or even for moderator-only review.  I've left a comment with a link for now, but what should be done in these cases?

Should the duplicate flagging be changed to allow flagging of duplicates even when answers aren't yet present?

Comment: Those two questions are *way* too similar to be a coincidence, IMHO, unless it's a homework question (which does happen). you could flag it for a mod to check. They're both low quality, so it might just sort itself out.

Comment: Except I can't mod-flag it as a duplicate either; that also requires an accepted answer.

Comment: You can flag it for (other) moderator attention and include a link to the other one.